# Redis cache tags flush memory leak

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

we using Laravel provided Redis tagged cache to cache query results for models in this way:

```
cache()->tags([model1, model2...])->remember(sql_query_hash, result_callback)
```

and if in example after some time and a users peak one of tags in example `model1` have 500k of unique cached queries, and there comes update and need to do :

```
cache()>tags([model1])->flush();
```

my job gets allowed memory exhausted, for workers we have 128MB of memory. Yes I know if I would increase memory of workers I could flush then 1kk of keys etc. but its not a right way because we have exponential users increase and our project will grow, so maybe some of tags will have 10kk of keys on users peak, and how then I have to flush a cache for tag?

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisTaggedCache.php#L174

this is how laravel flush tags keys, by retrieving all in memory then chunks it in memory again so this array_chunk double the memory usage after getting all keys, and then doing Redis::del operation to remove cached keys for this tag.

I don`t know how it call its a bug o not, but for me need some options does anyone dealing with that problem too, and maybe have some solutions?

Comment: Have you reported this to the github issue tracker? This may be limitation (undocumented/documented) as well as a bug.